# JS Interop causing thread-lock in Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a vertical list of items where draggable="true". When  A is initially dragged over  B [ondragenter], DoJsThingy() is called. DoJsThingy makes a call to a javascript function using IJsObjectReference.InvokeVoidAsync().

When I hover div A over div B, the alert is shown. When the alert is closed, the mouse pointer is still in the hover-over style from div A, and the app freezes.

The odd behavior is that the JS method executes and returns just fine. I validated this by throwing a simple WriteLine() just after it. The log message after InvokeVoidAsync is working, but it appears that DisposeAsync() is never getting called. If I remove the JS call, the app doesn't freeze after the hover event.

MyComponent.razor

```
@namespace BlazorWASM.Shared

@inject IDataService _dataService
@inject IUserService _userService
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<div class="sidebar-grid">
    <h2 class="data-models-header">Data Models</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" @bind="@searchString" class="search-bar" @bind:event="oninput" @onkeyup="() => UpdateSearchResults()" />
    <div class="data-model-list">
        @foreach (var model in searchResults)
        {
            <div @ref="listItems[model.Id]" draggable="true" class="@StyleDataModelListItem(model)" @ondragenter="() => DoJsThingy(model.Id)" @onclick="() => SelectDataModel(model)">
                <div class="data-model-list-item-icon-container">
                    <img class="data-model-list-item-icon" src="Images/data_model.svg" />
                </div>
                <div class="data-model-list-item-text">@model.Name</div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="data-model-save-load-buttons">
        <button class="new-data-model-button" @onclick="() => CreateDataModel()">New Data Model</button>
        <button class="delete-data-model-button" @onclick="() => DELETEITALL()">BIG Red Button</button>
    </div>
</div>



@code {
    public Dictionary<string, ElementReference> listItems = [];
    public string data = "";
    public List<DataModel> dataModels = [];
    public List<DataModel> searchResults = [];
    public DataModel? SelectedDataModel;
    public string searchString = "";
    private IJSObjectReference? module;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/test.js");
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _dataService.GetDataModelsBehaviorSubject().Subscribe(dms => {
            dataModels = dms;
            foreach(var dm in dataModels)
            {
                if (!listItems.ContainsKey(dm.Id)) listItems.Add(dm.Id, new ElementReference());
            }
            UpdateSearchResults();
            StateHasChanged();
        });
        _dataService.GetSelectedDataModelBehaviorSubject().Subscribe(sdm =>
        {
            SelectedDataModel = sdm;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
        _dataService.GetFieldLabelUpdatesBehaviorSubject().Subscribe(label =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    public async void RegisterUser()
    {
        await _userService.RegisterUser();
    }

    public async void CreateDataModel()
    {
        await _dataService.CreateDataModelAsync();
    }

    public async void ListDataModels()
    {
        await _dataService.LoadDataModelsAsync();
    }

    public void SelectDataModel(DataModel dataModel)
    {
        _dataService.SelectDataModel(dataModel);
    }

    public async Task DoJsThingy(string dataModelId)
    {
        try
        {
            var hoveredDataModel = _dataService.GetDataModel(dataModelId);
            if (module != null && hoveredDataModel != null)
            {
                await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert", hoveredDataModel.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Alert shown for model: " + hoveredDataModel.Id);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in DoJsThingy: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if(module != null)
        {
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }

    public string StyleDataModelListItem(DataModel dataModel)
    {
        var style = "data-model-list-item";
        if(SelectDataModel != null)
        {
            if (SelectedDataModel == dataModel)
            {
                style = "data-model-list-item-selected";
            }
        }
        return style;
    }

    public async Task DELETEITALL()
    {
        await _dataService.DELETEITALL();
    }

    public void DataModelListItemDragOver(string id)
    {
        var elementRef = listItems[id];
    }

    public void UpdateSearchResults()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            searchResults = dataModels;
        }
        else
        {
            searchResults = dataModels.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

test.js

```
export function showAlert(message) {
    alert(message);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues arise from your code.

You set `module` every time the component renders, which in drag operations is a lot.  The one you want to dispose will not be the one you created!

The `ondragover` event is for doing things such as changng the background color of an element when you move over it.  It's not the drop event.

Here's a demo that shows hoe to use the various events with some logging.  Run it and review the logs to see what's happening.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="list-group">
    @foreach (var country in _countries)
    {
        <div class="list-group-item" draggable="true"
             @key="country"
             @ondragstart="@((e) => OnDragStart(e, country))"
             @ondragover:preventDefault="true"
             @ondrop:preventDefault="true"
             @ondragover="@((e) => OnDragOver(e, country))"
             @ondrop="@(() => DoJsThingy(country))"
             @onclick="Clicked">
            @country
        </div>

    }
</div>

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? module;
    private string? _dragCountry;

    private List<string> _countries = new() { "France", "Uk", "Spain" };

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // only load it once
        if (firstRender)
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/test.js");
    }

    private void OnDragStart(DragEventArgs e, string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Drag Start: {data}");

    }

    private void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e, string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Drag Over: {data}");
    }

    public async Task DoJsThingy(string dataModelId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (module != null)
            {
                await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert", dataModelId);
                Console.WriteLine("Alert shown for model: " + dataModelId);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in DoJsThingy: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Clicked()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        // this only gets called when the component is no long part of the render tree and thr Renderer disposes it
        if (module != null)
        {
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

As to why you code locks the app, it's the number of events that are trying to do JS operations.

Comment: So my overall goal is to indicate where the dropped item will land. The vertical list of items will create an open space above the item that is being hovered over (by doubling the height of the list-item container, and putting the list item at the bottom of the container).